# Translating a query from Oracle into TSQL

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

I have a query which works very fast on Oracle.

`field1` and `field2` and `field3` are all integers

```
select * FROM MY_TABLE P WHERE   
USER_ID = 167 AND 
(field1,field2,field3) NOT IN 
( SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM EXCLUSION_TABLE)
```

I translated it into T/SQL (SQL Server 2008R2)

```
select * FROM MY_TABLE P WHERE   
USER_ID = 167 AND 
(cast(field1 as varchar)+ ','+cast(field2 as varchar)+ ','+
cast(field3 as varchar)) 
NOT IN 
( SELECT cast(field1 as varchar)+ ','+cast(field2 as varchar)+ ','+
cast(field3 as    varchar) FROM EXCLUSION_TABLE)
```

Has anyone got any ideas how I can do it differently?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure, you posted the correct Oracle query? You are selecting rows from my_table where one of (field1, field2, field3) is not equal to the **sum** of the three fields in `exclusion_table`. Are you sure this shouldn't be a tuple comparsion? e.g.: `(field1, field2, field3) not in (select field1, field2, field3 from exclusion_table)`

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name. I corrected the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
select * 
FROM MY_TABLE P 
WHERE USER_ID = 167 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        EXCLUSION_TABLE
    WHERE
        EXCLUSION_TABLE.field1=P.field1
        AND EXCLUSION_TABLE.field2=P.field2
        AND EXCLUSION_TABLE.field3=P.field3
)
```

You can do the same in oracle

Comment: +1 You've beat me by seconds but it seems like we had the same idea :)

Comment: Thank you to both arion and @lieven for your answers. I am going to accept arion because it was first.  I am going to edit my question as well, because I realize that the main reason the query was so slow is because there was some kind of lock on the table. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lieven : Yeah I know. I beat you by 23 seconds. It was quite fun that we had the same idea :P . But all the cred to you as well :)